# Economic effect of GEE coefficient

Tags: interpretation, stata, generalized-estimating-equations

**I am trying to calculate the economic significance/ magnitude of the coefficient of my independent variable:**

I am using a GEE model (`stata 14`) to regress my dependent variable Y on my independent variable X and control variales.

The following GEE options are used:

```
Link: log
Falimy: gamma
Correlation (of my dependent variale):ar2
```

The coefficient of my independent variable x is `0,238`.

My questions are the following:

When I want to interpret the economic significance of my coefficient, do I procede the same way as a coefficient of an OLS regression?
Hence, can I use the coefficient of my X to calculate the changes in my dependent variable Y to one-standard deviation increase of X? Or do I first need to alter the coefficient of my X  in order to properly calculate the economic significance?

I found the following related postings which suggest that the interpretation of my X-coefficient through GEE is the same as a normal OLS, only that they should be considered as an "average" coefficient for the whole population:
[Interpretation of GEE coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94779/interpretation-of-gee-coefficients), [Interpreting ordinal GEE coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247060/interpreting-ordinal-gee-coefficients?rq=1),
or here [Interpreting a longitudinal generalized estimating equations beta cofficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163058/interpreting-a-longitudinal-generalized-estimating-equations-beta-cofficients?noredirect=1&lq=1), which states that

> The betas are very similar in interpretation to those from OLS, but
>   for a population average.
>   This suggests that to calculate the economic significance, I can use the coefficient of my X generated through GEE and treat it as an OLS coefficient?!

However, I have found the following from Ballinger (2004):

> Because the log link function was specified, interpretation of the
>   value of the parameter estimates requires that they be exponentiated
>   by taking the log of the β coefficient estimates.

Does this mean, my first suggestion is false, and I first need to calculate the exponentiated value of my coefficient:

```
exp(0,238)
```

Thank you a lot in advance.

Ballinger (2004) Using Generalized Estimating Equations for Longitudinal Data Analysis, Organizational Research Methods, Vol 7, Issue 2